# Why God doesn't show any minor sakshatkaram as a ray or lightning in present 21st century?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, rishi, guru, vedic-gods

Unless God shows some sort of his/her power when devotee prays atleast by a ray or lightning mode of sakshatkaram in present 21st century belief will gets diminished?

Are there any Maha Guru's similar to Saptharishi's now in present 2019/2020 in 21st century?

Just placing Guru's hand on top of a person's head who suffered from a brain stroke should get healed instantly. Are there any Guru's now who can heals and liberate the person from sufferings with his/her tapo shakthi instantly like Saptharishis in present 21st century?

Comment: How do you know they are not? You think they will advertise themselves on the internet?? Do you think they have a facebook page? They do not care for name and fame, or 'likes'. You have to change to see them. They hide in plain sight.

Comment: "They do not care for name and fame, or 'likes'" well if they can make a lot money I am sure at least of them would advertise himself yet no one has up until this day thusly it is safe to say that those persons do not exist.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda “ You have to change to see them. They hide in plain sight.” <— I agree w/ this so much. In my experience the huge evil types and huge good/saint types, all of them are right in front of us looking like normal people. We can only see the reality when we change, like you say here.